# How to add class if i scroll outside specific div?

Tags: jquery

My problem is that i need fixed menu when i scroll to specific div and if im bellow or above div that menu dissapear.I manage to do that apperars when i come to that div but how can i disable it when it comes to the end? Any suggestion?

```js
$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('.compare-wrapper').position().top){
         $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','block');
     }
     else{

       $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','none');
     }
});
```

```css
.compare-wrapper{
  height:900px;
  background-color:white;
}
.header{
  height:600px;
}
.footer{
  height:600px;
}
.compare-menu-fixed{
 position:fixed;
 background-color: red;
 top: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
  left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.addressfinder.co.nz/assets/v2/widget.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header'>
</div>
<div class='compare-wrapper'>
      <div class="compare-menu-fixed">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <h2>Compare List <a href="#"><span class="active-img"></span></a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <h3>Hanse 455 <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Kastela</span></h3>
     <h4></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <h3>Hanse 455 <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Kastela</span></h3>
     <h4></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <h3>Hanse 455 <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Kastela</span></h3>
     <h4></h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='footer'>
</div>
```

EDIT: i found solution its great :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($("div.watch")[0].getBoundingClientRect());
    if ($("div.watch")[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom < 0)
        alert ("i'm out :3");
});
```

Comment: try my solution below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
      headH = $(".header").height();

    if (scroll >= headH) {
        $(".compare-menu-fixed").addClass("display");
    } else {
      $(".compare-menu-fixed").removeClass("display");
    }
});
```

```css
.compare-wrapper{
  height:900px;
  background-color:white;
}
.header{
  height:600px;
}
.footer{
  height:600px;
}
.compare-menu-fixed{
 position:fixed;
 background-color: red;
 top: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
  left:50px;
}
.display {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.addressfinder.co.nz/assets/v2/widget.js"></script>
<div class='header'>
</div>
<div class='compare-wrapper'>
      <div class="compare-menu-fixed">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <h2>Compare List <a href="#"><span class="active-img"></span></a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <h3>Hanse 455 <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Kastela</span></h3>
     <h4></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <h3>Hanse 455 <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Kastela</span></h3>
     <h4></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
     <h3>Hanse 455 <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Kastela</span></h3>
     <h4></h4>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='footer'>
</div>
```

I edit my answer, now `.compare-menu-fixed` get `display:none` if it scroll to end of `.header`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1839/)

Comment: it not working well ... because it disapear on half of div

Comment: @None Ok now im sure that this is what you want, i updated my answer and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1839/) Please tell me if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Is not accurate when scrolling up.